# Apply tint to grayscale png image with transparency in Java

Tags: java, colors, bufferedimage, alpha

I need to apply a tint to a grayscale BufferedImage with transparency without influencing the transparency itself, this is the method i use, but when i try to draw it on top of another image inside a canvas, the transparency of the original image is gone, leaving a square of the raw selected color...

```
private BufferedImage colorize(BufferedImage original,Color tint) { //TODO fix!!!

BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(original.getWidth(), original.getHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);

int redVal=tint.getRed();
int greenVal=tint.getGreen();
int blueVal=tint.getBlue();

for (int x=0;x<original.getWidth();x++) for (int y=0;y<original.getHeight();y++) {
    Color pixelVal=new Color(original.getRGB(x, y));
    int grayValue=pixelVal.getRed();  //Any basic color works the same
    int alpha=pixelVal.getAlpha();
    int newRed= (redVal*(grayValue))/255;
    int newGreen= (greenVal*grayValue)/255;
    int newBlue= (blueVal*grayValue)/255;
    img.setRGB(x, y, new Color(newRed,newGreen,newBlue,alpha).getRGB());
}
return img;}
```

Any hint?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/21385150/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`Color` constuctor that takes two arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color%28int,%20boolean%29):

```
 Color pixelVal = new Color(original.getRGB(x, y), true);
```

This constructor creates a `Color` with an ARGB color, if the `hasAlpha` parameter is `true`.

The single argument constructor `Color(int)` does *not* take transparency into account. From the JavaDoc:

> Creates an opaque sRGB color with the specified combined RGB value [...] Alpha is defaulted to 255.

Apart from that, your code should probably work. :-)