# Color Combination

Tags: java, colors, color-scheme

I have a grey image containing at least 20 different shades of gray. I would like to apply a certain color without changing it with the exception of the grey affecting the colors brightness slightly. I don't want a very drastic modification to color, only a hint. How would I go about doing this?

I'm using java, however I am more interested in the concept behind doing this.

Comment: In reality I'm using the gray as a brightness, so the surface doesn't look too plain. I want the applied color to take on the brightness of the grey shades, without changing the color too much

Comment: What you are probably looking for is ["blend modes"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes), e.g. how to blend colors. From what I can understand, I think the mode "multiply" would fit your needs. As can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/unrLC/) (example using JS, CSS, HTML).

Comment: Actually, I think what you want is to use HSV colour space - set the V value from the grey, but keep H and S the same as the original colour.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21382966/colorize-a-picture-in-java/21385150#21385150

Comment: Marco, the problem with the method you posted is that he is using transparent color to dye the image. I'm looking for a slightly simpler, and faster way as I would be using this in a game

Comment: I've checked out the different methods you guys have posted, and I believe the best option is probably converting to and from hsv. Thanks for all the help

Comment: Well, the Java `Color` class has a method `getHSBColor` and two static methods `HSBtoRGB` and `RGBtoHSB` which you can look up the Javadoc for.  I don't know why these method names refer to HSV as HSB; but it's the exactly same thing.

Comment: Figures 2a and 2b on [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) will help you decide whether HSV or HSL is more appropriate for your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How would I get the hsv values of a color in Java?

Don't know about HSV, but you could probably use HSL instead. Check out [HSL Color](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/05/hsl-color/) for a class that does the conversion.