# changing image color in java

Tags: java, image

I am trying to change color of image. Hence I used the following code

```
public class Picture {

String img_name;
BufferedImage buf_img;
int width;
int height;

public Picture(String name) {
    this.img_name = name;

    try {
        buf_img = ImageIO.read(new File(img_name));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Picture.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

public Picture(int w, int h) {
    this.width = w;
    this.height = h;
    buf_img = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
}

public int width() {
    width = buf_img.getWidth();
    return width;
}

public int height() {
    height = buf_img.getHeight();
    return height;
}

public Color get(int col, int row) {
    Color color = new Color(buf_img.getRGB(col, row));
    return color;
}

public void set(int col, int row, Color color) {
    buf_img.setRGB(col, row, color.getRGB());
}

public void show() {
    try {

        File saveAs = new File("D:\\temp\\" + new Random().nextInt() + ".png");
        ImageIO.write(buf_img, "png", saveAs);

        Desktop.getDesktop().open(saveAs);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Picture.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
   }

 }

public class ColorSeparation {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // read in the picture specified by command-line argument
    Picture picture = new Picture("D:\\qwe1.jpg");
    int width = picture.width();
    int height = picture.height();

    // create three empy pictures of the same dimension
    Picture pictureR = new Picture(width, height);


    // separate colors
    for (int col = 0; col < width; col++) {
        for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
            Color color = picture.get(col, row);
            int r = color.getRed();
            int g = color.getGreen();
            int b = color.getBlue();
            pictureR.set(col, row, new Color(r, 0, 0));

        }
    }

    // display  picture in its own window
    pictureR.show();

  }

}
```

It is working as expected. [image: input Image]

[image: Output image].

Now I want to set color of entire image to rgb 255, 153, 51. I tried to set
`pictureR.set(col, row, new Color(255, 153, 51))`. But the resulted output is the below image[image: resulting image].

How can I get correct image? Please help.

Comment: That looks a lot like an image where you have "set color of entire image to rgb 255, 153, 51" to me.

Comment: Post the `Picture`  class. Better still, post a [mcve]

Comment: @Reimeus I have updated the question now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your initial example is misleading you. Your code in the first example is setting varying shades of red (pulled from the original red channel), creating a "redscale" image, not "colorizing" the image like you think it is.

```
int r = color.getRed();
pictureR.set(col, row, new Color(r, 0, 0));
```

Your second example is setting a fixed color for each and every pixel, so you get a uniform orange.

```
pictureR.set(col, row, new Color(255, 153, 51))
```

You need to colorize the image by varying all three channels, just like you varied the red value initially. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21382966/957950) for an example using compositing, which is a different angle from what you're using now.

The easiest implementation for you, given your sample code, would be to calculate the [relative luminence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_luminance) of each pixel (effectively it's grayscale value) and use that to adjust the "orange" value you are setting. The standard weighting for luminence is

```
L = 0.2126*R + 0.7152*G + 0.0722*B
```

so something like

```
pictureR.set(col, row, new Color(255 * L/255, 153 * L/255, 51 * L/255));
```

Comment: The color co ordinates are exceeding the limit giving Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Color parameter outside of expected range: Red Green Blue

Comment: @swapnilgandhi Correct, L is in the range 0-255 so muliplying it by the pixel values exceeds the RGB value range (also 0-255). I have updated my answer to convert L to a percentage (divide it by 255) while setting color channels. You may want to use a non-uniform weighting (like the weights in the `L` formula) in your solution, depending on your desired result.

Comment: Luminence didnt work, but the other thing did. Thanks a lot.