# Image or Graphics2D color filter

Tags: java, awt

How could a color-filter be applied to a BufferedImage (or Graphics2D) in Java. Same functionality as a layer in Photoshop with overlay type 'Color'.

I tried painting with an AlphaComposite, but it's just not the same :)

Comment: For those of us who don’t have Photoshop, can you explain the filter in more detail?  Does it show only the red (or green or blue) component of each pixel?

Comment: It changes the color (hue), but does not change saturation or brightness, I think. What I am trying to do, is change the color of a grayscale image. Looks great in Photos hope, but I am unable to reproduce same result with AWT.

Comment: Something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21382966/colorize-a-picture-in-java ?!

Answer (score 0):

I’m sure nothing I offer will match the complexity of Photoshop, but at the very least, you can colorize a grayscale image by using an [RGBImageFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/RGBImageFilter.html) to alter one or more of the RGB components of each pixel:

```
int redIncrement = 0;
int greenIncrement = 0;
int blueIncrement = -64;

ImageFilter filter = new RGBImageFilter() {
    @Override
    public int filterRGB(int x,
                         int y,
                         int rgb) {
        int alpha = (rgb & 0xff000000);
        int red = (rgb & 0xff0000) >> 16;
        int green = (rgb & 0x00ff00) >> 8;
        int blue = (rgb & 0x0000ff);

        red = Math.max(0, Math.min(0xff, red + redIncrement));
        green = Math.max(0, Math.min(0xff, green + greenIncrement));
        blue = Math.max(0, Math.min(0xff, blue + blueIncrement));

        return alpha | (red << 16) | (green << 8) | blue;
    }
};

Image filteredImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(
    new FilteredImageSource(image.getSource(), filter));
```